# Why this function that print array in reverse doesn't work

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function that print array in reverse, but it doesn't work for me.

this is what I wrote (on online C compiler site):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_reversed(int* a)
{
    
    if (a[0]==0) {
        break;
    }
    print_reversed(&a[1]);
    printf("%d", a[0]);
}    
   

int main()
{
    int array [7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0};
    print_reversed(&array[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

`0` indicate the end of the array.

I know there is a problem with the break statement but I don't know how to solve it.

I know there are other solutions but I need to solve it in that method.

(I'm learning the basic so maybe it stupid question).

thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you think `break` means?

Comment: Tip: `&a[1]` can also be written `a+1`. Both are equally acceptable.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I though it will end the function and by that it will not call the function again.

Comment: Tip : `int array[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0};` can also be written `int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0};` It will determine the correct size from the initializer, avoiding mistakes from having duplicate information.

Comment: Tip: Since you're not modifying the pointed values, `const int* a` is better than `int* a`.

Comment: @ikegami Why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246321/discussion-between-alfa-hores-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error or similar:

```
<source>: In function 'print_reversed':
<source>:7:9: error: break statement not within loop or switch
    7 |         break;
```

As it says, `break` only works in a loop or a switch statement.

To return from a function, you want `return`.

Comment: I though that I can't use `return` in void function. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `return x`, but you can use `return`.

Comment: Which will just immediately exit the function without executing the following code in that function.